# c socket server response

Tags: c, sockets, fork

This is my socket server with fork:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void do_child(int sock);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        perror("./server <numero porta>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_t pid;
    int DescrittoreServer, DescrittoreClient, LunghezzaClient;
    int NumPorta = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr; /* indirizzo del server e del client */
    char Buffer[1024] = {};
    DescrittoreServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(DescrittoreServer < 0){
        perror("Errore: creazione socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); /* bzero scrive dei null bytes dove specificato per la lunghezza specificata */
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* la famiglia dei protocolli */
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(NumPorta); /* porta */
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* dato che è un server bisogna associargli l'indirizzo della macchina su cui sta girando */

    if(bind(DescrittoreServer, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("Errore di bind\n");
        close(DescrittoreServer);
        exit(1);
    }
    listen(DescrittoreServer, 5);
    LunghezzaClient = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while(1){
        DescrittoreClient = accept(DescrittoreServer, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &LunghezzaClient);
        if(DescrittoreClient < 0){
            perror("Errore: non è possibile stabilire la connessione\n");
            close(DescrittoreServer);
            close(DescrittoreClient);
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            perror("Fork error");
            close(DescrittoreServer);
            close(DescrittoreClient);
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid == 0){
            close(DescrittoreServer);
            do_child(DescrittoreClient);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            close(DescrittoreClient);
        }
    }
}

void do_child(int sock){
    int n;
    char Buffer[1024] = {};
    n=read(sock, Buffer, 255);
    if(n < 0){
        perror("Errore nella lettura dalla socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    recv(sock, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0);
    printf("Dati ricevuti: %s\n", Buffer);
    strcpy(Buffer, "Dati ricevuti correttamente!");
    send(sock, Buffer, strlen(Buffer)+1, 0);
}
```

without fork the server and the client work perfectly but after i've introduced the fork i got a strange behaviour from them.
Let's try to explain it:
Behaviour **without** fork: the client send the message "Ciao sono il client" and the server give the response "Dati ricevuti correttamente".
Behaviour **with** fork: nothing happen until i press "CTRL-C" on the client (i'm on Ubuntu). After i've pressed CTRL-C the server print the message from the client.
I don't understand why the messages sharing are not "on demand" but only when i stop the client or the server :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do_child()` code `read`s from the socket first (and then `recv` again after this), before writing, whereas your parent code contains no socket write code at all (at least the snippet you provided didn't) so is it possible that your `do_child()` function is blocking while you read data that is not being sent???

Comment: You're right! i have removed the "read" and now all work properly :D thanks"